# SharePoint 2010 Search doesn't return strings last char if it's ' " '

Tags: search, sharepoint-2010, quotes, quotations

I have a list of companies in my SharePoint 2010 server, and most of the items in it (not all) have a title of syntax like `"Company Name"` . Although when I search for a company on my search page, it returns a title like `"Company Name` without last quotation mark. I made a solution to add

`<xsl:if test="contains(title, '&quot;')">"</xsl:if>`

to my search results xslt, and it works just fine, but I want to know if it's a SharePoint bug, or maybe this problem is solved in the just released Service Pack 2? Thanks!

Comment: Please ask me if you have any questions or need some more information :)

Answer (score 0):

Once I had a similar problem, I think it's a bug indeed, cause I didn't find any information... The search results return that value without last quote from crawl database, even though in database crawled properties those values has the last quote... I solved my problem by changing that fields type from `single line of text` to `multiple lines of text` it works correct with that kind of fields, so if you can use multiple lines of text for that field you can solve it this way :) But, in my opinion, your solution is even better for some purposes :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I thought so... well, I can't use multiple lines of text for that field, but anyway, i'll give you my bunty as it's no time left, so it would go for nothing :)